# Libreoffice 6.4.7 for 20.04.x LTS

Tags: apt, libreoffice

Libreoffice recommends 6.4 for production use as the 7.x release is not yet recommended for "business" use.  The final release of 6.4 is 6.4.7 that does have a deb package from LibreOffice, but not Ubuntu as of my most recent search today.
[Libreoffice 6.4.7 deb-x86_64 download](https://www.libreoffice.org/donate/dl/deb-x86_64/6.4.7/en-US/LibreOffice_6.4.7_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz)
When will there be an Ubuntu production package for 20.04.x LTS of Libreoffice 6.4.7?

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1906684, the tracking bug for the 6.4.6 update to 6.4.7. Everything you want to know is there.

Comment: I respectfully disagree -- everything does not seem to be in the URL above that is from  2020-12-22 in terms of the last comment from Amr Ibrahim (amribrahim1987).  In the interim, libreoffice.org has released a production (not RC) of Libreoffice 6.4.7 that is recommended for production use instead of 6.4.6 and has a .deb file for download.  Will this file work if downloaded?  Will Ubuntu "official" have a 6.4.7 production package?  When Libreoffice 7.x is regarded as stable for "business" use, will Ubuntu official produce a 20.04 LTS package?

Comment: The Canonical engineer explained in comment #1 of the bug report **exactly** why there is currently no plan to package 6.4.7 for Ubuntu. Since neither you nor I pay their salary nor set their work priorities, that's the way it will be. You are welcome to test the upstream package (we have not). You are welcome to help diagnose the problem(s) with 6.4.6. You are welcome to organize a group of volunteers to test 6.4.7 and upload it (instead of waiting for Canonical engineers to do it). More volunteer contribution is welcome,

Comment: I apologise if I misread what the Canonical software engineer stated.  RC (release candidates -- "beta" -- not production) were under discussion.  The current 6.4.7 release from Liberoffice is (supposed to be) production.  However, there are many deb based environments -- I assume that unless a DEB package is *VERY* "plain vanilla" ("generic", or fully self contained in so far as is possible under the Linux monolithic kernel architecture), such a package may not work or may "break" some current DEB packaged distro (such as LTS current).  Is that the situation as you read the URL you provided?

Answer (score 0):

For such case you can always use one of the “LibreOffice Packaging” team [PPAs](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice):

**to get 6.4**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-6-4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**to get latest 7.0.4 (recommended way, will work with 18.04 LTS too)**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

Note: to revert the changes use [`ppa-purge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ppa-purge.1.html) - `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`, `sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-6-4` or `sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa` .

Comment: @NOrbert.  Instead of following your PPA suggestion, I download the actual deb.tar.gz files from the Libreoffice official URL, for 6.4.7 production (not RC) release.  I then "un-tgz'ed" these and used ```sudo apt install *.deb```  to install.  These .deb files installed separately from the official Ubuntu 6.4.6 so that both the official and 6.4.7 production generic deb are installed, and I may use each (if these are in fact encapsulated from each other, as I expect).  I will report any difficulties I encounter with 6.4.7 contrasted with 6.4.6.  I am not using 7.x until it is for "business".